# Support SQL Server 2005 and 2008

Tags: .net, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, sql-server-2008-r2

i want to know how it is possible to use the Entity Framework against the SQL Server 2008 and 2005?

I develop a application against the SQL Server 2008 and want that it can run under 2005 and 2008.
I know that it is possible to change the ProviderManifestToken from 2008 to 2005 in the edmx Schema File in a Texteditor. But after i update my Model from the Database it changes the ProviderManifestToken back to 2008.

How can i told Visiual Studio to use the the 2005 Schema when i update my model from Database?

Thanks for any Help!

Nico

Answer (score 1):

Read my [blog post](http://www.programmingmotility.com/2011/05/setting-providermanifesttoken-for-sql.html) on EF and ProviderManifestToken.

Using the [MSBuild.Community Tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/), I added a BeforeBuild Target that uses the XmlUpdate task to always change the ProviderManifestToken to 2005, in case someone changed it by updating the data model.

Here is the BeforeBuild Target:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild"> <XmlUpdate Prefix="ssdl"
            Namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl"
            XPath="//ssdl:Schema/@ProviderManifestToken"
            XmlFileName="Model.edmx"
            Value="2005"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the manual (hack!) edmx change is the only way at the moment. Particularly annoying when you forget and deploy it to an environment with 2005. :)

I'd like to know another way...

Comment: Checkout my [blog](http://www.programmingmotility.com/2011/05/setting-providermanifesttoken-for-sql.html) for another suggestion using a BeforeBuild target in MSBuild.

Comment: Hello Jack. Thanks for the update, that's a good blog post. I'll give it a go when I have some time.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to put your source database into SQL 2005 compability mode (level 90) on your SQL 2008 server. You can use ALTER DATABASE to do that.